# How to add JavaDoc information about Annotations in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, javadoc

is there a possibility to add JavaDocInformation for the Annotations that are used in Hibernate for example for Annotations like `@Entity`, `@Table` etc..?

And for which jar-File I had to add these files?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must not use a jar. You can use a link to the online documentation. For hibernate hier is a link:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/

If you use eclipse, click to the project -> build path -> configure build path. Under Libraries choose the hibernate libraries, open it and click to Javadoc location -> edit. Add the link or the jar-File. Link to the jar http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/

Comment: I've only added the JavaDocs (from the hibernate-release-4.3.8.Final-folder) for hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar - is there other jars for which I have to add the javadocs?